# best way to obtain one answer that satisfy a linear equation in matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-programming, linear-equation

I have a linear equation:

```
vt = v1*x1 + v2*x2 + v3*x3
```

vt, v1, v2, v3 are scalars with values between 0 and 1. What is the best way to generate one set (any set will be fine) of  x1, x2 and x3 that satisfy the equation above. and also satisfy

```
x1>0
x2>0
x3>0
```

I have couple thousand sets of vt,v1,v2 and v3, therefore I need to be able to generate x1, x2 and x3 programmatically.

Comment: The fastest way would be to set `x1` and `x2` to be known and solve for `x3`.  `x1` and `x2` could be set by you, or they could be randomly generated.  If you randomly generate them, you should make sure that `vt` is less than `v1*x1 + v2*x2`.  You could also use `linprog` and form this into a linear program and solve for it.  Does it matter if `x1` and `x2` are the same?

Comment: @rayryeng This was my initial thought as well. I can't think of a somewhat clever way to randomly generate x1 and x2 and ensure vt<v1*x1 + v2*x2 (I know I can keep randomly generate x1 and x2 until the condition is met).

Comment: @rayryeng also, it is preferable if x1 and x2 are drawn from some distribution (e.g. a uniform distribution) randomly (randomly with some constraint).

Comment: That's ok.  We can avoid this all together by using `linprog`.  I'll write an answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways you could approach this:

1. From the method that you have devised in your post.  Randomly generate `x1` and `x2` and ensure that `vt < v1*x1 + v2*x2`, then go ahead and solve for `x3`.
2. Formulate this into **linear program**.  A linear program is basically solving a system of equations that are subject to inequality or equality constraints.  In other words:

[image: blah]

As such, we can translate your problem to be of a linear programming problem.  The "maximize" statement is what is known as the objective function - the overall goal of what you are trying  to accomplish.  In linear programming problems, we are trying to minimize or maximize this objective.  To do this, we must satisfy the inequalities seen in the **subject to** condition.  Usually, this program is represented in **canonical form**, and so the constraints on each variable should be positive.

The maximize condition can be arbitrary as you don't care about the objective.  You just care about any solution.  This whole paradigm can be achieved by [`linprog`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html) in MATLAB.  What you should be careful with is how `linprog` is specified.  In fact, the objective is **minimized** instead of maximized.  The conditions, however, are the same with the exception of ensuring that all of the variables are positive.  We will have to code that in ourselves.

In terms of the arbitrary objective, we can simply do `x1 + x2 + x3`.  As such, `c = [1 1 1]`.  Our equality constraint is: `v1*x1 + v2*x2 + v3*x3 = vt`.  We also must make sure that `x` is positive.  In order to code this in, what we can do is choose a small constant so that all values of `x` are greater than this value.  Right now, `linprog` does not support strict inequalities (i.e. `x > 0`) and so we have to circumvent this by doing this trick.  Also, to ensure that the values are positive, `linprog` assumes that the `Ax <= b`.  Therefore, a common trick that is used is to negate the inequality of `x >= 0`, and so this is equivalent to `-x <= 0`.  To ensure the values are non-zero, we would actually do: `-x <= -eps`, where `eps` is a small constant.  However, when I was doing experiments, by doing it this way, two of the variables end up to be the same solution.  As such, what I would recommend we do is to generate good solutions that are random each time, let's draw `b` to be from a uniform random distribution as you said.  This will then give us a starting point every time we want to solve this problem.

Therefore, our inequalities are:

```
 -x1 <= -rand1
 -x2 <= -rand2
 -x3 <= -rand3
```

`rand1, rand2, rand3` are three randomly generated numbers that are between `0` and `1`.  In matrix form, this is:

```
 [-1 0 0][x1]      [-rand1]
 [0 -1 0][x2]  <=  [-rand2]
 [0 0 -1][x3]      [-rand3]
```

Finally, our equality constraint from before is:

```
[v1 v2 v3][x1]     [vt] 
          [x2]  = 
          [x3]
```

Now, to use `linprog`, you would do this:

```
X = linprog(c, A, b, Aeq, beq);
```

`c` is a coefficient array that is defined for the objective.  In this case, it would be defined as `[1 1 1]`, `A` and `b` is the matrix and column vector defined for the inequality constraints and `Aeq` and `beq` is the matrix and column vector defined for the equality constraints.  `X` would thus give us the solution after `linprog` converges (i.e. `x1, x2, x3`).  As such, you would do this:

```
A = -eye(3,3);
b = -rand(3,1);
Aeq = [v1 v2 v3];
beq = vt;
c = [1 1 1];
X = linprog(c, A, b, Aeq, beq);
```

As an example, suppose `v1 = 0.33, v2 = 0.5, v3 = 0.2`, and `vt = 2.5`.  Therefore:

```
rng(123); %// Set seed for reproducibility
v1 = 0.33; v2 = 0.5; v3 = 0.2;
vt = 2.5;
A = -eye(3,3);
b = -rand(3,1);
Aeq = [v1 v2 v3];
beq = vt;
c = [1 1 1];
X = linprog(c, A, b, Aeq, beq);
```

I get:

```
X =

0.6964
4.4495
0.2268
```

To verify that this equals `vt`, we would do:

```
s = Aeq*X

s = 2.5000
```

The above simply does `v1*x1 + v2*x2 + v3*x3`.  This is computed in a dot product form to make things easy as `X` is a column vector and `v1, v2, v3` are already set in `Aeq` and is a row vector.

---

As such, either way is good, but at least with `linprog`, you don't have to keep looping until you get that condition to be satisfied!

## Small Caveat

One small caveat that I forgot to mention in the above approach is that you need to make sure that `vt >= v1*rand1 + v2*rand2 + v3*rand3` to ensure convergence.  Since you said that `v1,v2,v3` are bounded between `0` and `1`, the worst case is when `v1,v2,v3` are all equal to 1.  As such, we really need to make sure that `vt > rand1 + rand2 + rand3`.  If this is **not** the case, then simply take each value of `rand1, rand2, rand3`, and divide by `(rand1 + rand2 + rand3) / vt`.  As such, this will ensure that the total summation will equal `vt` assuming that all of the weights are 1, and this will allow the linear program to converge properly.

If you don't, then the solution will not converge due to the inequality conditions placed in for `b`, and you won't get the right answer.  Just some food for thought!  As such, do this for `b` before you run `linprog`

```
if sum(-b) > vt
   b = b ./ (sum(-b) / vt);
end
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One question, so does vector b corresponds to the -eps? in that case does it make sense to do something like b = -rand(3,1)*0.0001? @rayryeng

Comment: @Cici - Yes, which is what I noted in my Small Caveat.  Multiply the `rand` by something small to ensure that we get an answer.  Other than that, this should hopefully give you what you're looking for.

Comment: now I see why b = -rand(3,1)*0.0001 is not a super great idea! since sometime it just return an answer that is too close to zero.

Comment: @Cici - Which is why you should scale it according to what I have specified in my Small Caveat.  That way, you won't get solutions so close to 0.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I should add that, your answer is super easy to extend to a system that have N number of variables in the linear equation. super awesome! @rayryeng

Comment: @Cici - You're very welcome!  I made a small correction to the Small Caveat.  I didn't divide properly.  Good luck!